# How do you get rid of a white right margin on iPhone's Safari for a web site?

Tags: iphone, mobile, mobile-safari, responsive-design

I've converted an existing site theme (that I did not build) into a responsive theme for mobile support. It's a Drupal 6 site, if that matters.

I'm getting a slight right white margin on most interior pages, and I can't seem to find the culprit. I've tried setting the body width to 100%, setting overflow-x to hidden on the body tag, and outlining all the divs in red to find the culprit.

Do you know of any causes of a right margin on mobile Safari?

View port setting:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

The right side margin is not for scrollbar, as this margin differs from sites that fit right like cnn.com

An example interior page:

```
http://nano.omnidev3.com/nanotech-101
```

(Trying to avoid a Google index. This demo site is *not* under my control, so I can't put in the normal measures I would to properly prevent a stage site from being indexed.)

Comment: Does it by any chance have the width of a scroll indicator? (I think this was a typical Android issue) Did you set the viewport correctly? Do you have a link to a site demonstrating this?

Comment: Thanks, I added information for both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say this, but that is one piece of disgusting HTML. 20+ CSS includes, 10+ javascripts, divs nested 10 levels deep...

Anyway, if the (logical) width of the device is 320px (i.e. all iPhones) then doing this:

```
<iframe src="http://meltwaternews.com/magenta/xml/html/93/2/v2_371253.html"
    width="343" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    allowtransparency="true" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
```

will make the page 343px wide, giving a white edge. Nothing special.

Try setting it to `320px` or `100%`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this! Kindly note that I did say "I did not build this theme..." ;)

Comment: I think maybe you are looking at the home page. I was focused on the interior pages. But thanks for this, I fixed it with JS.